# Is there faster way to compute an if condition with "any or all" function in the for loop?

Tags: matlab

For example, the time for computing fallowing piece of code is not efficient for my program.

```
b=[10,11,14,9];
a=[13,10,18,11];
tic
for i=1:14166133
   if any(a>b)

   end
end
toc
Elapsed time is 20.655411 seconds.
```

Is there faster way to do this?

Comment: What's the significance of `i` there?

Comment: Please include the actual function you are using within your `if` statement, so we (actually @Divakar) can vectorise it.

Comment: I highly doubt you can speed up the code you have shown at all. However, what you intend putting inside that `if` might be able to be optimized to not need the `if` or better yet not need the loop. But to answer the question as it stands, I highly doubt there is a faster way.

Comment: It's impossible to give a useful answer with the information provided, I vote to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear.

Firstly you should not compute the comparison every time.

```
b=[10,11,14,9];
a=[13,10,18,11];
tic
c = a > b;
for i=1:14166133
   if any(c)

   end
end
toc
```

Comment: You could even take `any` outside the loop...

Comment: Yes, but in the title he mentioned something about the performance of 'any'